# Principal ideals in rings.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Consider the following list of principal ideals (2), (3), (5), (6) in the ring ℤ/14ℤ. There are :

- a) Only one ideal in this list.
- b) Two distinct ideals in this list.
- c) Three distinct ideals in this list.
- d) Four distinct ideals in this list.

I know the answer is related to divisors of 14, but I am not sure which answer is correct. I would eliminate a) and d), and my feeling is that the right answer would be c).

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can explicitly enumerate the elements of each ideal and compare them (as suggested by @jammarqz), I like the following approach:

Note that there is a natural isomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}/(14))/(n)\cong \mathbb Z / (14,n)$, but $\mathbb Z$ is a PID and the ideal generated by $14$ and $n$ will be the ideal generated by their GCD.  So all you have to do is compute the GCD of $14$ and the numbers in the question.

Comment: And what am I looking for exactly ? The ones that give a gcd equal to 1 ? Then 3 and 5 would work.

Comment: Or simply the ones with the same gcd are equal ? Then (2) and (6) would be equal and (3) and (5) too ?

Comment: @ThéodoreRozencwajg You are looking for how many of the ideals are distinct.  3 and 5 yield the same ideal because they yield the same GCD. 2 is different because GCD(2,14) is different from GCD(3,14).

Comment: @ThéodoreRozencwajg Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 4):

The ideal $(n)$ in $\mathbb Z/14\mathbb Z$ is the image of the ideal $(n,14)$ in $\mathbb Z$ under the canonical quotient map.

Now $(n,14)$ in $\mathbb Z$ is equal to $\gcd(n,14) \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. The multiples $(2)=\{2,4,6,8,12,0\}$ is an additive subgroup, but also ideal.

But also note that $(3)=\{3,6,9,12,1,4,7,10,13,2,5,8,11,0\}$, which is the whole ring.

Comment: So the answer is a) and the one ideal is (3) ?

Comment: $(2)$ is a proper ideal. $(3)$ is improper.

Comment: What's the difference ? Does that change the answer to the question ?

Comment: extrictly $(2)\subset \Bbb Z/14\Bbb Z$, but $(3)=\Bbb Z/14\Bbb Z$

Comment: Do we still consider that (2) and (3) are distinct or not ?

Comment: clearly they are different

Comment: Then the answer to the question would be b) 2 distinct ideals, because (2) and (6) are equal and (3) and (5) too, right ?

Comment: .. right - right